# Content-Type application/json doesn't return POST fields

Tags: php, json, xml, curl, header

I'm making cURL request to file on my server And it's printing empty array, unless I delete Content-Type: application/json header from request. Why it occure? It should expect json format in return....

```
$o = [ 'key' => 'value123' ];

        $headers[]  = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $headers[]  = 'Moj-pierwszy-header: prosty/do/zapamietania';


        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path.'test.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $o);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);      



        echo( $output );
```

and the test.php

```
echo json_encode( $_POST );
```

Anybody? Any ideas?

Comment: You're not posting JSON...

Comment: @AbraCadaver it doesn’t work even when I encode sending string.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below code snippet:

```
     $o = json_encode([ 'key' => 'value123' ]);

     $headers[]  = 'Content-Type: application/json';
     $headers[]  = 'Moj-pierwszy-header: prosty/do/zapamietania';


    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path.'test.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $o);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 

    echo( $output );
```

and for output, instead of $_POST use below code snippet:

> $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Hope, it'll work for you.

Comment: I’ve tried to send $o as encoded json but still got an empty array as a result. Have you checked if it’s work on server?

Comment: in test.php, try $post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); to receive the posted data. It'll work.

Comment: unfortunately I got a message: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ucado3/external-CMS/headers request response test/test.php on line 14

Comment: ok found my problem, I've tried to echo result in test.php and its fine unless your'e not trying to echo array :) it works just fine I need to check this 'php://input' parameter more deeply. Thumb up